# redirect_uri_mismatch in soundcloud connect after rails upgrade

Tags: ruby-on-rails, soundcloud

I have a soundcloud app that has been working without issue for at least 4 years now.
We recently upgraded the version of Ruby on Rails that we run and this seems to have broken the Soundcloud Connect process.

that process now returns with a URI_REDIRECT_MISMATCH error yet, none of our app settings have changed, and it seems, soundcloud have since disabled new app registration and editing of existing apps.

i was hoping someone could help me solve this.. any answers welcome. thank you

Comment: kindly consider adding more information in your question, e.g. code errors etc

Comment: which Rails version are you upgrading to?

Comment: did your soundcloud or oauth gems update? That would be my guess — one of the earlier versions of said gem might have used a different endpoint for said authorization process. Check this with `cat Gemfile.lock | grep soundcloud` on your before/after.